# How can I match the last two words in a sentence in PostgreSQL?

Tags: regex, postgresql

Have been trying for a while, to match the last word of a sentence:

```
select regexp_matches('My name is Harry Potter', '[^ ]+$');
```

returned {Potter}

to try to match the last two words:

```
select regexp_matches('My name is Harry Potter', '[^ ]\s+[^ ]+$');
```

failed.

```
select regexp_matches('My name is Harry Potter', '(.*?)\s+(.*?)$');
```

Did not word as intended either.

Any insights?

Comment: And `'[^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+$'`? Or  `select regexp_matches('My name is Harry Potter', '(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)$');`

Comment: Try `'\w+\W+\w+$'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, thanks! your solution '[^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+$' worked!

Comment: I will post the solution then

Comment: yup, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use double escaping in the pattern since it seems the `standard_conforming_strings` parameter of your PostgreSQL instance is turned off. See [PostgreSQL 9.5.3 Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS):

> `standard_conforming_strings (boolean)`
>   This controls whether ordinary string literals (`'...'`) treat backslashes literally, as specified in the SQL standard. Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is on (prior releases defaulted to off).

Thus, you need to use

```
'[^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+$'
      ^^
```

or

```
'\\S+\\s+\\S+$'
```

Here,

- `[^ ]+` - 1 or more characters other than a space (any non-whitespace if `\\S` is used)
- `\\s+` -  1 or more whitespaces
- `[^ ]+` - 1 or more characters other than a space (any non-whitespace if `\\S` is used)
- `$` - end of string anchor.

Comment: You only need the double backslash if you have standard conforming strings turned off, which is not the default start with v9.1: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS

Comment: @Nicarus: That is a very useful link, thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `REGEXP_MATCHES` which returns an array of matches, you may be better off using `SUBSTRING` which will give you the match as `TEXT` directly.

Using the correct pattern, as @Abelisto shared, you can do this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('My name is Harry Potter' FROM '\w+\W+\w+$')
```

This returns `Harry Potter` as opposed to `{"Harry Potter"}`

Per @Hambone's comment, if either of the words at the end contain punctuation, like an apostrophe, you would want to consider using the following pattern:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('My name is Danny O''neal' FROM '\S+\s+\S+$')
```

The above would correctly return `Danny O'neal` as opposed to just `O'neal`

Comment: Great answer.  If you also want to capture special characters (so words like "don't" appear, you may want to use space and non-space in your regex:  `'\S+\s+\S+$'`

Comment: @Hambone - Good suggestion, I will update the post to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how the regex works for postgres, but
[online regex testers](https://regex101.com/) tell me that `.*\s(.+)\s+(.*?)$` might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but this regex matches the last two words of a sentence, and it's similar to your initial regex: "[^ ]+\s+[^ ]+$" (I just added a '+'.)

For further testing, I suggest going to https://regex101.com/ It's one of the best online regex helpers I've found, and it even breaks down the regex for you. (I'm not involved with the site in any way - it's a recommendation, not a plug)