# PostgreSQL return last n words

Tags: postgresql

How to return last n words using Postgres.

I have tried using **LEFT** method.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(name, -4) FROM my_table;
```

but it return last 4 characters ,i want to return last 3 words.

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? And is it safe to assume the words are delimited by (single) spaces?

Comment: @stickybit **postgres** , yes words are delimited by spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c7c516a609a95a1e6689e3cbd6d673b2)

You can do this using a the `SUBSTRING()` function and regular expressions:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(name FROM '((\S+\s+){0,3}\S+$)') 
FROM my_table
```

This has been explained here: [How can I match the last two words in a sentence in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754634/how-can-i-match-the-last-two-words-in-a-sentence-in-postgresql)

`\S+` is a string of non-whitespace characters

`\s+` is a string of whitespace characters (e.g. one space)

`(\S+\s+){0,3}` Zero to three words separated by a space

`\S+$` one word at the end of the text.

-> creates 4 words (or less if there are no more).

Comment: What do you mean? Can't you simply use the DISTINCT clause?

Answer (score 0):

`RIGHT()` should do

```
SELECT RIGHT('MYCOLUMN', 4); -- returns LUMN
```

**UPD**

You can convert to array and then back to string

```
SELECT array_to_string(sentence[(array_length(sentence,1)-3):(array_length(sentence,1))],' ','*') 
FROM
(
SELECT regexp_split_to_array('this is the one of the way to get the last four words of the string', E'\\s+') AS sentence
) foo;
```

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=28648aa9be7b7b49833a66ed7b9f14cf)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `regexp_split_to_array()` to split the string into the words it contains and then put a string back together using the last 3 words in that array.

```
SELECT coalesce(w.words[array_length(w.words, 1) - 2] || ' ', '')
       || coalesce(w.words[array_length(w.words, 1) - 1] || ' ', '')
       || coalesce(w.words[array_length(w.words, 1)], '')
       FROM mytable t
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT regexp_split_to_array(t."name", ' ') words) w;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=4740db5a8fbab0e5371e48478292e7f4)