# Retrieve the last 3 words of a string using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to retrieve the last 3 words of a string using regex.

The string - "From the place on July 19, 2019"

I need to extract only the date part 'July 19,2019'.

I tried the below ways :-

```
(\w{3})$             # gives last 3 letters of the last word
([,0-9]{3})$         # gives last 3 digits from the last word
(?:\w+\s*){1,3}$     # retrieves only the last word
```

None of them gives me the last 3 words.

Comment: So Does the data will always in the last?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA yes. The date will appear only at the end on these strings. And in the same format.

Comment: So the answer in the link can solve your problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please provide the regex part. I had initially tagged python, because this regex is an input to a python script. Basically i need the regex that does this retrieval first.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i removed the 'python' tag. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you were the one who flagged this question as duplicate, could you please undo it ? Kindly ignore if it wasn't you. Thank you.

Comment: It is still a dupe. As in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38768601/3832970), your solution is with an extra `\S+\s+`: `\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+$`. Or `\S+(?:\s+\S+){2}$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That was a postgre specific question to be fair. Never mind.

Comment: So, the regex pattern is the same across all NFA engines. I would not close with that one if it were a POSIX one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
string = "From the place on July 19, 2019"
mobj = re.search(r"\b(\w+(?=\s\d+,)\s\d+,\s?\d+)", string)
date = mobj.group(1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print(date)
July 19, 2019
```

Comment: @Thanks. Although wondering why there isn't a more simple regex.

Comment: @Salih May be you could try `(\w+\s(?=\d+,)\d+,\s?\d+)`

Comment: `\s\w+\s\w+[,\s].{1,2}\w+$`, The reason why the regex is longer is because of the comma in the date.  Posting this solution here because the question asked for last 3 words not the last month word + last 2 numbers. also you can test it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match